ARMA estimation before GJR-GARCH. How to proceed with multiple time-series?
I want to study the Conditional Variance of various crypto-currencies returns series (13, of which 5 meme, 8 "serious"). Since my main focus is the asymmetric response of the variance against past returns I am using a GJR-GARCH model.
Doing a Ljung-box test I noticed how autocorrelation is detected only on 3 of my 13 currency sample.
These are my doubts:

Before estimating the GJR-GARCH, should I apply an ARMA model to all time-series regardless of autocorrelation and then work on the residuals, or should I apply an ARMA only to the autocorrelated series and work directly on the returns on the non autocorrelated ones?

Should I tailor the Arma model to each series through AIC/BIC or should I apply the same model to all series to treat them equally (i'm 99% sure i should not treat them equally, but that 1% bugs me).


Consider that the point of this analysis would be to compare the variance response and the leverage of all 13 cryptos with each other.
